# clear the java cache from the command line in linux

Tags: java, linux, caching

The title says it all. I have to clear the java cache (to load a fresh version of an applet) from the command line, and the command line only, without any GUI.

I tried something found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25807154/4142984

```
javaws -clearcache
```

But it opens a GUI that leads me to a window for the Java Control Panel.

The window (seen remotely on a windows machine) is non-resizable, and the interesting buttons from "*Temporary Internet Files*" are not in the visible part of the window.

Comment: as for the usual un-commented down-votes, I will delete this question soon, no need to start a vote to close because unclear what is asked

Comment: As my question now has an accepted answer, I'll not delete the question but see what will happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, I thought you were talking about Java memory cache...

I think you got downvoted because your question is out of topic, and unclear. From this "GUI", you must see where your cache is stored.

Mine is here: `/home/ju/.cache/icedtea-web/cache` ; then I must do

```
rm -rf /home/ju/.cache/icedtea-web/cache/*
```

to remove its content.

Comment: nice, so I simply have to remove the directory!.

Comment: `/*` means the *content only*. Better leave the directory.

Comment: I would have deleted the contents but not the directory by instinct, or all by laziness, thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 2):

There's the option `-silent` in `javaws`. According to documentation, it prevents UI for importing (installing) applications to the cache. But who knows, maybe it has effect on removing them too.

Comment: Thank you, but at least on the system where I happen to be, it simply opens the GUI.

Comment: Actually, java applet cache is just a bunch of files in a special place. Deleting them will have the same effect as javaws -uninstall. These files are usually placed in the user's home directory. Try look in /home/userid/.java/deployment/cache.